# OCSP with libcrypto and libcurl

Tags: c, libcurl, libcrypto

I'm writing an application which needs to verify the validity of certificates. For that I'd like to use OCSP. Rather than implementing OCSP myself, I was looking at OpenSSL's `libcrypto` to prepare the necessary data.

I came up with this (error handling removed for clarity):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SSL_library_init();
    FILE *cert_f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *cacert_f = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    X509 *cert = d2i_X509_fp(cert_f, NULL);
    X509 *cacert = d2i_X509_fp(cacert_f, NULL);
    fclose(cert_f);
    fclose(cacert_f);

    OCSP_REQUEST *req = OCSP_REQUEST_new();
    OCSP_CERTID *id = OCSP_cert_to_id(EVP_sha1(), cert, cacert);
    OCSP_request_add0_id(req, id);
    BIO *bio = BIO_new_connect("ocspserver:http");
    OCSP_RESPONSE *resp = OCSP_sendreq_bio(bio, "/2", req);
}
```

Which sends out the request just fine. Only the problem is that `OCSP_sendreq_bio()` does not appear to support sending HTTP requests via an HTTP proxy, which is a blocker for me. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/OCSP_REQ_CTX_set1_req.html) has the following to say about that:

> These functions only perform a minimal HTTP query to a responder. If an application wishes to support more advanced features it should use an alternative more complete HTTP library.

Only it doesn't say how to do so, and I can't seem to figure it out. The `OCSP_sendreq_bio()` call does the conversion of the `OCSP_REQUEST` struct to an ASN.1 structure, but there don't appear to be any public calls that allow me to do so (unless I'm missing something).

Am I going about this the right way? If not, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot :-)

The answer is that OpenSSL has a bunch of macros that generate generic functions for converting something from `struct`s to the ASN.1 binary format. These all have the form `i2d_STRUCT_NAME` (and `d2i_STRUCT_NAME` for the reverse operation). The exact `i2d_OCSP_REQUEST` and `d2i_OCSP_RESPONSE` functions aren't documented, but some others (e.g., `d2i_X509`, which I'm friggin' using in my question) are and have a very similar function signature (since they're generated with the same macro).

The answer is thus to replace `OCSP_sendreq_bio` with something like this:

```
unsigned char *data = NULL;
long len = (long)i2d_OCSP_REQUEST(req, &data);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ocspserver/2");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, (long)1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, len);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_memory_append_function);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

etc.